# Get path of a network drive folders

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

I am trying access files within a folder of a network drive using c# `FolderBrowserDialog`, all it shows me are the local drives and the network drives on my computer.

Is there a way of getting access to folders of a network drive? I am using a UNC path for this:

```
\\\\servername\\folder\\subfolder
```

I know that there is a way to get the selected path

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
fbd.SelectedPath = "C:\\Test\\";
fbd.ShowDialog();
```

Would this enable me to see the network drive folders? Any help on this is most welcome

Comment: The place I am working from currently doesnt have a network drive

Comment: You can find the answer quite easily by searching for a solution on google

Comment: @GBh Even `\\localhost\c$` isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"\\10.0.0.1\myFolder\test\")
```

Comment: Using this would signify that folder browser dialog cannot map the network drives. I have used an input box as of now, is there any way of making the user "select" a network path rather than paste it?